# Display Current Posts Category (with the most posts)?

Tags: posts, categories

I have an post article, with a title date and the category the post is assigned to.
The post is in multiple categories, but i only want to show the 'main' one its in and none of the others (for now).

How do i search through all the categories the post is assigned to and only show the one with the most posts in? Therefore giving that category the idea as the main one?

I assume cycling through `get_the_category` counting all the posts within all the categories assigned to this post and then picking the one with the most?

```
$category_main = get_the_category(); //But only the one with the more posts than the others?

if ( ! empty( $category_main ) ) {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category_main[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $category_main[0]->name ) . '</a>';
}
```

Thank you for any ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_the_category()` returns an array of `WP_Term` objects, so you already have access to the `count` property - just sort the array by it and retrieve the one with the highest count:

```php
$main_category = current( wp_list_sort( get_the_category(), [ 'count' => 'DESC' ] ) );
```

Check out the documentation for [`wp_list_sort()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_sort/)

Comment: Perfect thank you :)